# 'flutter' doesnt recognize as a name in cmdlet

Tags: json, powershell, flutter, flutter-dependencies, powershell-cmdlet

im following a tutorial of flutter about using json and serialization.
Im trying to execute a command in the terminal in a flutter proyect in vscode,

this is the class

```
import 'package:json_annotation/json_annotation.dart';

part 'mensaje.g.dart';

@JsonSerializable()
class Mensaje{
  final String subject;
  final String body;

  Mensaje(this.subject,this.body);

  Mensaje.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json):
    subject=json['subject'],
    body=json['body'];

}
```

I first add the dependecies in pubspec.yaml:

dev_dependencies:

build_runner:
  json_serializable:

then i try to execute in the terminal in vscode this line:

flutter packages pub run build_runner build

and the error:
(flutter its not recognize as a cmdlet name or function... )

```
flutter : El término 'flutter' no se reconoce como nombre de un cmdlet, función, 
archivo de script o programa ejecutable. Compruebe si escribió correctamente el 
nombre o, si incluyó una ruta de acceso, compruebe que dicha ruta es correcta e 
inténtelo de nuevo.
En línea: 1 Carácter: 1
+ flutter packages pub run build_runner build
+ ~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (flutter:String) [], CommandNotFoundEx  
   ception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Las preguntas y respuestas aquí deben estar escritas en inglés. Por favor utiliza http://es.stackoverflow.com. (Questions and answers here must be written in English. Please use https://es.stackoverflow.com/.)

Comment: can you tell me what i have to edit so you can open my question again?

Comment: You just need two more people to vote to reopen (I have). Or delete it and repost it in English. (Or in Spanish on https://es.stackoverflow.com/.)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you need to add your Flutter SDK path to the environment variable (e.g. C:\src\flutter) for windows. Also you can follow the Flutter documentation for proper installation on different OS:

- [Windows](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/windows)
- [macOS](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/macos)
- [linux](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/linux)
- [Chrome OS](https://docs.flutter.dev/get-started/install/chromeos)

If this is not the case, you can try to restart your VSCode application.